# how to hide toolbar items in e4 application with specific perspective

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I am currently working with e4 application where I want to hide some `toolbar buttons` when the application is in certain perspective. In eclipse 3.x, I used to do it by perspective property tester using extension. But in e4, is there any way to do the same?

Comment: A HandledToolItem can have a 'visible when' core expression. But it looks like you might have to write your own property tester to use the EModelService getActivePerspective API and use that in the expression.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for the help .Is eclipse neon supports perspective switcher by default or we have write it on our own

Comment: You have to write your own.

Comment: rajesh, try this will help in implementation. https://github.com/vogellacompany/e4-perspective-switcher

Comment: @ArdeshanaMilan I implemented on my own man  Its a simple one  We were using this previously .Thanks for the help

Comment: Also I have seen simple combo box as perspective switcher. You are welcome! :)